# php simple html dom parser not updating multi classes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, css

I'm trying to apply 2 classes to an element like this:

```
$div->setAttribute('class', 'txt found');
```

unfortunately it won't work as i'm getting the following markup:

```
<div found="" class="txt">
```

I've also tried `$div->class = "txt found";` which had same result.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following;

```
$div->className = "txt found";
```

Updated:

```
<?php
$divHtml = "<div></div>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($divHtml);
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$divElement = $allElements->item(0);
$divElement->setAttribute("class", "txt found");
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

I tried to reproduce your case and finally it worked.You can test it.If you send more code we can modify it inorder to work

Comment: already tried that - leads to: <div classname="txt found" class="txt">
it would be a workaround if it was possible renaming attributes (classname -> class) ..

Comment: i think it's a bug in the parser .. this occurs if you don't use quotes for attributes containing spaces .. the parser sets the attribute like this: <div class=txt found> which leads to found=""

Comment: I have updated the code, could you please try that? If you have send more code we can modify it